# Restore Oracle Database From Oradata Folder

Tags: oracle, database-restore, rman

I have lost my database on the server because the computer has been formatted on drive C. But the oracle folder was located on Drive E, like oradata, etc. Can I restore oracle database like before?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need to install the oracle server with the version which was there before formatting.

Follow these steps:

1. Install the same Oracle database version with the starter database.
2. Copy all control files, datafiles to oradata directory
3. Copy init.ora filr to ADMIN folder
4. Revise the init.ora file for the changed control file, archive and dump locations. (keep instance, SID, and global db name the same)
5. Create the instance by running oradim with the pfile(init.ora) location
6. Connect to DB using internal and mount it.
7. Check existing data and logfile locations by typing:

   ```
   SELECT name FROM V$DATAFILE;
   SELECT member FROM V$LOGFILE;
   ```
8. Now change the file locations that come up above by using:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE RENAME FILE <old file loc list> to <new file loc list>;
   ```
9. After renaming them open the database by alter database open.

And you should be set.

[Reference](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1042016-COLD-back-up-HOW-CAN-I-RESTORE)